# error while pushing to heroku - Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Got this error while pushing to heroku:

```
 Installing oa-enterprise (0.2.1)
   /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:365:in `
est': too many connection resets (http://production.cf.rubygems.org/gems/oa-
-0.2.1.gem) (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:28
 `open_uri_or_path'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:29
 `open_uri_or_path'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:17
 `fetch_path'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:11
 `download'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/sou
rb:254:in `download_gem_from_uri'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/sou
rb:71:in `fetch'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/ins
er.rb:45:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spe
t.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spe
t.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/ins
er.rb:44:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/ins
er.rb:8:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli
225:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/ven
thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/ven
thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/ven
thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/ven
thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/ven
thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/bundle:19
   FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
   Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler
```

How can I solve it ?

Thanks,

Oded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`too many connection resets` might been caused by the connection between your server (Heroku) and RubyGems' CloudFront CDN.

There has been some reports of issues today on Amazon AWS services, which you can check here:

http://status.aws.amazon.com/

CloudFront was having issues which could have been the root of your issue.

Can you try again? I don't think your gems are the problem, but more a network fluke.

Comment: yeah I guess that was the problem cause it just worked the next day.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have a gem in your `gemfile` that cannot be be found or installed. List your `gemfile` and I will tell you which one it is.

Copy and paste the following bundle.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.3" 
gem 'aws-s3' 
gem 'devise' 
gem 'omniauth', '0.2.0'
gem 'httparty' 
gem 'nifty-generators'
```

Then:

```
bundle
git add .
git commit -m 'new bundle'
git push heroku
```

Then you can add your development gems later, this is just to get production working first.

```
group :development do
    gem 'mocha' 
    gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2' 
    gem 'jquery-rails' 
    gem 'faraday', '0.6' 
    gem 'uuidtools' 
end
```

FYI - the problem was with oauth gem. I just took the one from heroku.

Comment: gem 'rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.3"
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'nifty-generators', :group => :development
gem 'mocha'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'faraday', '0.6'
gem 'uuidtools'